# Thumbnails fade in fade out randomly

Tags: image, for-loop, opacity, fade

I am new here, facing difficulty.

here is my questions:

I want to load multiple images randomly as same as below link.

http://priyasriartgallery.com/_test/index.html

After load all images thumbnails should be keep fading. if you see there are images opacity is 50%. it should be 100% opacity but randomly.

Anyone can make nicer code?

Thanks All Masters.

/* Below Is My code */

// JQuery Init*******************************

$(document).ready(function(){

```
   $(".box").hide();


   var speed = 10; //speed in ms

    $(window).load(function() {

        timer= setInterval(function fadeInDiv(){

             $notLoaded = $(".box").not(".loaded");
             $notLoaded.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*$notLoaded.length))

                    .fadeIn()
                    .addClass("loaded");




             if ($notLoaded.length == 0) {


                setTimeout(function(){
                $notLoaded.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*$notLoaded.length))
                $('.box > p > img').fadeTo("slow", 1).delay(10000).fadeTo("slow", 0.5)
                $('.box > img').fadeTo("slow", 0.5).delay(2000).fadeTo("slow", 1)

                });



             }



       }


        , speed);

        }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

randomly select the images add a class in format "rand_img_X" and get/set opacity css property..
the property opacity takes float values 0.5 is your 50%

Comment: I want like this: images fade in loop after load but randomly. http://jsfiddle.net/U8spY/

Comment: Anyone can make 10 images highlight at a time, randomly.
http://jsfiddle.net/aditya_shinde/U8spY/67/

Thanks